# REST PUT success but no change

Tags: category, magento-2.1, api, rest-api

I am calling REST PUT to change a category name (one that I am testing) and the response is 200 with the correct new name. When I do a REST GET on the id to get the category back it is again the correct name.

But when I am in administration the category name has not changed.

Could it be related to cron jobs not running?

I ran them manually but still no change.

**UPDATE:** When testing the same process with a product it works fine. I can POST a product and update it's name with a PUT.

**UPDATE2:** Logged a [bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7831) with Magento.

**UPDATE3:** In the db the REST PUT call seems to insert a new record with the wrong store ID (1). With sample data loaded the store ID should be 0. Need to figure out how to set the store ID through REST PUT.

**UPDATE4:** REST PUT works but it changes the name in Default Store View level and not at root level (All Store Views). I have yet to find a way to set the store view ID to 0 in the REST PUT call (or why it defaults to 1)

Comment: did you get any error or exception? please check the log once and paste here so that we can try to resolve the issues.

Comment: Any idea which log I should be looking at? Again, note that the changes do persist when I call the GET service, so it makes me wonder why admin doesn't see them.

Comment: Nothing in the logs. Just checked.

Comment: Setup a new instance with latest version CE 2.1.3 and the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the answer the hard way.

Always use the store code in your url to the endpoint to ensure you are tapping the right store.

For PUT you need to place it at the end as a parameter "store_id" and for POST you need to set it as described here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/rest_endpoints.html

See my bug comments here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7831

**UPDATE** For anyone that may find it useful I wrote a complete guide here: http://undefined.gr/site/2016/12/22/magento-2-1-3-rest-api/